# Create object from referencing variable

Tags: vb.net

I have the variable

```
Public __REPORT_FORM As Form
```

declared in a module. I am also setting a value to this variable like

```
__REPORT_FORM = frmReport
```

Now I need to know how to create an object of type `frmReport` using the variable `__REPORT_FORM`.

For example something like this is what I'm trying to achieve

```
Dim myObj As Form = New __REPORT_FORM
```

If this is possible please share an example.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you need to open a form again you could use the same instance, if you want to open a similar form you could use a factory method which returns an instance of this form like `GetReportForm As Form`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am declaring the variable in module, so that it is easy to change. It's for like a framework purpose.

Comment: you could use a generic function.  declaring the form type as Form will be problematic down the road.  consider combining the generic (if you have to) with the factory method.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing instances and types. `frmReport` is not a type, it is apparently an instance of an object of a particular type if you are assigning it to something. If you are assigning it to __REPORT_FORM in a Module, then it is a Shared instance, as in the instance is the same for all objects that access it in your process.

When you write this line of code:

```
Dim myObj As Form = New <Type>
```

`<Type>` should be a type name, not a variable or field. You *could* use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx) to have "type parameters" if you are trying to parameterize your types, but that depends more on the context of your code and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am declaring the variable in module, so that it is easy to change. It's for like a framework purpose. If I hard code frmReport the code will show errors if the frmReport is not found on the solution explorer.